# I want to convert a .mat file into excel

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jxyms.png)the type of data is numpy.ndarray. I am trying to convert it to pandas data frame with following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.io import loadmat


data= loadmat(r"EAOW_FLOW_TimeSeries_1hr_LocationA1_final.mat")

ary = np.array(data)

ser = pd.Series(ary)

df=pd.DataFrame(ser)

df.to_csv(r"data.csv", index=False)
```

this is generating an excel but all the data is in single cell.

I am new to python. please help me resolve this error and convert the mat file to csv

Comment: Show the full error.  Explain what `ser = pd.series(x)` is supposed to be doing?

Comment: i changed my code and now i am able to generate a csv but all data is in one cell

Comment: hpaulj is asking for the complete error and what you want your code to do so we can help you. Imagine you tell us "My hammer works on all my nails, except this one nail", but you do not show us the nail. Later, after many comments, we find out it's a screw. Please tell us _everything we need to know in the question_.

Comment: thank you so much for taking interest. but there is no error from the above edited code..it is generating an excel but all the data comes up in one cell..there is no tabular format. I  am not allowed to paste images yet here. There is a link to the SS

Comment: But what's in that `cell`?  You need to examine what you loaded before going through all that `array/Series/DataFrame` conversions.  We don't have your mat file, so can't help with that.  `loadmat` produces a `dict` with a number of items from the file, including headers, and one or more variables.  Read the `loadmat` docs.  You don't want to convert that whole dict to array and so on.  Most likely you'll want just one variable from it.  But depending on what that variable was in MATLAB, it might be a very complex array.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CuJkO943Pbdjw_ib4w_ovU2zZPhlfaVC/view?usp=sharing this is the link for shared location of that excel

Comment: That image with a cell that starts with `{'__head` looks like the string rendering of a `dict`, with the first item having key like '__head'.  That's what I'd expect from `loadmat`.  You need to unpack that dict, selecting variables etc.  My guess is that this is too big of a project for someone who is new to Python, and not something that we can help with remotely.

Comment: i seee...thankyou for help..but i would still like to have some answers..any tutorials..anything which could help

Comment: when i print type of the ary it is showing <class 'numpy.ndarray'> and shape is ()

Comment: And it is object dtype.  That `np.array(data)` step was useless, as was all the following pandas sruff.